# Interaction between potent cantrip and sculpt spell: Thunderclap

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard, cantrips

According to DnD 5e wizard evoker subclass lvl 2 feature Sculpt Spell, you could prevent 1 friendly adjacent creature from taking damage from a *Thunderclap* cast by your evoker (it would automatically save the CON save and suffer no damage).

Also, according to evoker lvl 6 feature Potent Cantrip, cantrips that would normally do no damage on a failed save now do half damage (including, I'm assuming, *thunderclap*). Taken to the letter, this would mean that getting the lvl 6 feature Potent Cantrip would be detrimental to your character, at least with regard to the casting of *Thunderclap*, since the spell would now harm your friend near you? Am I getting this right?

It may well be the case, but it seems a little bit unfair. Could you choose to apply the Potent Cantrip feature only to your enemies when casting a *Thunderclap*? Could you choose not to apply Potent Cantrip to a given *Thunderclap* cantrip casting at all to prevent friendly fire?

Comment: And welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] to learn more about us and you can also visit the [help] for more information.

Comment: Can you explain why you have Empowered Spell in your Title but Sculpt Spell in the body of your question?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Sculpt Spells states that:

> The chosen creatures automatically succeed on their saving throws
>   against the spell, and they take no damage if they would normally take
>   half damage on a successful save. (PHB 117)

So even if the spell is affected by Potent Cantrip, Sculpt Spells would still negate all damage to a chosen creature.

Comment: I had misunderstood the sculpt spell feature, you're totally right, thank you.